# How to call user defined datatype during casting

Tags: postgresql, casting

I have table that has a schema defined, and one of the columns has a user defined data type.

Now I am ingesting data into the database as JSON object, so while querying the data I would like to call the data type on the fly.

Table `a`:

```
id  name            type
1   id              text
2   summary         text
3   Investigator    UDT1
4   Instance        UDT2
```

Right now I am manually casting, which works fine, but I am struggling with passing it on the fly.

```
SELECT id,
       cast(d.* as tempdb.ref_investigator)
FROM tempdb.values_temp t,
     jsonb_populate_record(
        null::tempdb.ref_investigator,
        t.value::jsonb
     ) d
WHERE t.id IN ('F15','F16')
```

---

```
("1","summary1","KUM,  HYE-CHUNG",kum@tamu.edu)
("2","summary2","Zakon,  Harold",h.zakon@mail.utexas.edu)
```

Comment: The call to `jsonb_populate_record` doesn't look right. Maybe you can share your actual code.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe this is my actual query, i have removed unnecessary columns which might cause confusion,
SELECT id, cast(d.* as tempdb.ref_investigator) FROM   tempdb.values_temp t , jsonb_populate_record(null::tempdb.ref_investigator, t.value::jsonb) d where t.id in ('F15','F16')

Comment: I tried to edit the question accordingly, but I still cannot make head or tail out of it. Please edit it some more and make it clearer: 1) What is the relationship between table `a` and `values_temp`? 2) How does the data sample relate to the question? 3) What are the actual names of `UDT1` and `UDT2` (so we know how that related to the query) 4) What exactly do you want to do "on the fly"? Don't be afraid to be verbose.